# how do i draw a vertical line below my vertical hyperlink? html css

Tags: html, css

im trying to place my vertically aligned hyperlink on top of a vertical line. to demonstrate this when its working in the right way, let's use the alphabet "i". the dot represents my hyperlink whereas the stroke below represents the vertical line i am trying to code.

after researching, coded this styling:

```css
.vl {
  border-left: 4px solid #25374C;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="v1">
</div>
```

well, these did not show anything on my webpage. i have tried using

tag, doesnt work too.

Comment: your css says vl ( V L ) but your html is v1 (V ONE)

Answer (score 2):

just create a `column` `flex-box` and align items to the `center`.

```css
.line {
  height: 20px;
  width: 4px;
  background: red;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <a href="">hyperlink</a>
  <div class="line" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css :

```css
.v1 {
  border-left: 4px solid #25374C;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There have already been a few answers and comments posted in this thread that will help you to create a vertical line with a `<div>`. But as always you have some more options.

If you feel like the line is inseparable from the link, like the line in your example from *i*, then you might look at it as content instead of styling. Then a simple solution like this would be possible as well:

```css
p{ writing-mode: vertical-lr; }/* or use vertical-rl */ 
a{ text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<p><a href="#">link</a> ————</p>
```